# Preencher input com valor de objeto através da chave dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, objetos

Tenho uma planilha onde preciso preencher automaticamente um campo a partir do valor digitado em outro campo, onde a base são os valores de um objeto.

Exemplo: Tenho o objeto:

```
objeto = {
    10:0.9997,
    11:0.9996,
    12:0.9995
}
```

Quando digitar 10 em um campo, o outro campo teria o valor preenchido com `0.9997`. Já tentei adaptar alguns códigos que pesquisei e não consegui. Agradeço se puderem me ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, Sílvio.

Você pode fazer:

```js
var objeto = {
    10: 0.9997,
    11: 0.9996,
    12: 0.9995
}

function mostrarValor(valor) {
    var caixaValor = document.getElementById("caixa-valor")
    if(typeof objeto[valor] !== "undefined") {
        caixaValor.value = objeto[valor]
    } else {
        caixaValor.value = "Valor não encontrado"
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Chave</p>
<input type='text' onkeyup='mostrarValor(this.value)'>
<p>Valor</p>
<input id='caixa-valor' type='text'>
```

Nesse código, recebemos o valor digitado na caixa de texto cada vez que o evento `keyup` acontece dentro dela. Como esse número é a própria chave do valor procurado no objeto, basta fazermos `objeto[chave]` e teremos o valor desejado. Após isso, basta imprimir esse valor dentro da outra caixa de texto, como você desejou.

Adicionalmente, se inserimos uma chave que corresponde à um valor não existente em nosso objeto, receberemos um `undefined` ao fizermos `objeto[chave]`. Para mostrar uma mensagem de erro ao usuário, podemos fazer um if verificando se  `objeto[chave]` é do tipo undefined.

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu estava querendo fazer, adaptei no meu código e funcionou direitinho. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Fico feliz que tenha funcionado :D